# EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Cannot detect ES version Spark-ElasticSearch example

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, spark-streaming

I am trying to run simple data write to ElasticSearch example. However, I keep getting this error:

```
EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Cannot detect ES version - typically this happens if the network/Elasticsearch cluster is not accessible or when targeting a WAN/Cloud instance without the proper setting 'es.nodes.wan.only
```

My dependencies for Spark and ElasticSearch:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.5"

val sparkVersion = "2.3.0"

resolvers += "Spark Packages Repo" at "http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion,
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.0",
  "org.elasticsearch" %% "elasticsearch-spark-20" % "6.2.4"
)
```

Here is my code for an example:

```
object App {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
      .setMaster(args(0))
      .setAppName("KafkaSparkStreaming")
    sparkConf.set("es.index.auto.create", "true")

    val sparkSession = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .config(sparkConf)
      .getOrCreate()

    val streamingContext = new StreamingContext(sparkSession.sparkContext, Seconds(3))
    val sparkContext = streamingContext.sparkContext
    sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sparkContext)

    val numbers = Map("one" -> 1, "two" -> 2, "three" -> 3)
    val airports = Map("arrival" -> "Otopeni", "SFO" -> "San Fran")

    sparkContext.makeRDD(Seq(numbers, airports)).saveToEs("spark/docs")

    streamingContext.start()
    streamingContext.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

I run ElasticSearch with docker image. It is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  kafka:
      image: spotify/kafka
      ports:
        - "9092:9092"
      environment:
      - ADVERTISED_HOST=localhost
  elasticsearch:
      image: elasticsearch
  kibana:
      image: kibana
      ports:
        - "5601:5601"
```

What might cause this exception? I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/correct-settings-for-es-nodes-wan-only/58743 should help you

Comment: I saw it. And it doesn't give any solutions to this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar situation while trying to experiment spark with elasticsearch, replacing "elasticsearch-spark" dependency with "elasticsearch-hadoop" to meet my elasticsearch ver. solved the problem

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Sample").setMaster("local[*]")
conf.set("es.index.auto.create", "true")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(10))

val numbers = Map("one" -> 1, "two" -> 2, "three" -> 3)
val airports = Map("arrival" -> "Otopeni", "SFO" -> "San Fran")

val rdd = sc.makeRDD(Seq(numbers, airports))
val microbatches = mutable.Queue(rdd)

ssc.queueStream(microbatches).saveToEs("spark/docs")

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

dependency list

```
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.0",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.2.0",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % "2.3.1",
"org.elasticsearch" %% "elasticsearch-hadoop" % "6.3.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can edit your spark config by adding your ES hostname:

   ```
    sparkConf.set("es.index.auto.create", "true") 
    sparkConf.set("es.nodes", "your_elasticsearch_ip")
    sparkConf.set("es.port", "9200")
    sparkConf.set("es.nodes.wan.only", "true")
   ```
2. You can also try to forward you ES port in your Docker-compose file:

   ```
    elasticsearch:
      image: elasticsearch
      ports:
        - "9200:9200"
   ```
3. If it is not work, maybe it is a probleme with the Spark connector so you can redirect your calls to ES to your local:

   In your docker-compose add this command:

   ```
    elasticsearch:
      image: elasticsearch
      command: "apt install -y socat && socat tcp-listen:9200,fork tcp:your_elasticsearch_ip:9200 &"
   ```

   Or

   ```
    command: "apt install -y socat && socat tcp-listen:9200,fork tcp:localhost:9200 &"
   ```

socat will **forward your local 9200 port to your remote elasticsearch** 9200 port.